# Toric fano threefolds

Tags: algebraic-geometry

According to Batyrev, there are exactly 18 types of smooth toric Fano threefolds. As projective toric varieties, these are defined by the normal fan of certain 3-dimensional polytopes. Does anyone know of a reference where these polytopes are listed, e.g., as convex hulls of points?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google immediately finds [Smooth toric fano varieties and their polytopes](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/users/kasprzyk/research/pdf/GAELTalk.pdf) by A. Kasprzyk, which has *pictures* of the 18 polytopes. Surely following the references therein should get you coordinates of the vertices.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I already looked at that paper. The pictures are nice, but it is hard to make out what the polytope is explicitly. The references there refer to Batyrev's original paper, which I cannot find anywhere.

Comment: @user6064: you can always ask the author, you know: he surely knows the coordinates :)

Comment: Sure I could do that, but since this is so well-known, I was hoping it would be on-line somewhere :)

Comment: It probably is, and Kasprzyk probably knows where!